# Text view in fragment not changing colour

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm trying to change the colour of text for my text view within my fragment of my activity but nothing changes because of this error:

```
Cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
```

What can I do to resolve this?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WCBank_textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TabWCBankTerminus extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_wc_bank_terminus,container,false);
        return v;

        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.WCBank_textView1);
        txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFD300'>text0</font>" +
                        "<font color='#00A4A7'> text1</font>" +
                        "<font color='#E32017'> text2</font>" +
                        "<font color='#FFFFFF'> text3</font>"
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `onCreateView` you have two errors. First you are return statement has to be, in your case, the last one, otherwise the statements that follow are unreachable. Second you have to invoke `findViewById` through `v`. Differently from `Activity`, Fragment has no `findViewById` method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_wc_bank_terminus,container,false);       
    TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.WCBank_textView1);
    txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFD300'>text0</font>" +
                    "<font color='#00A4A7'> text1</font>" +
                    "<font color='#E32017'> text2</font>" +
                    "<font color='#FFFFFF'> text3</font>"
    ));
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Fragment` does not define a `findViewById()` method, you need to use the `View` object (`v`) to call it.
The reasoning behind this is, the `Fragment` does not know anything about the layout until it's inflated. You're inflating the layout and returning a view object that contains information about the stuff you're trying to configure, so you need to invoke the method on the `View` object instead of the `Fragment`.

Change to:

```
TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.WCBank_textView1);
```

Then you `return v` at the very end of your method, not before you make the configuration changes.

It should look like this when you're done:

```
public class TabWCBankTerminus extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_wc_bank_terminus,container,false);

        TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.WCBank_textView1);
        txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFD300'>text0</font>" +
                        "<font color='#00A4A7'> text1</font>" +
                        "<font color='#E32017'> text2</font>" +
                        "<font color='#FFFFFF'> text3</font>"
        ));
        return v;
    }
}
```